# Error running Rmpi when doing parallel computing

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to running parallel computing in R with below lines

```
library(parallel)
library(snow)
library(snowFT)
library(VGAM)
library(dplyr)
library(Rmpi)

nCores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(nCores)
```

Then R returns an error

```
Error in Rmpi::mpi.comm.spawn(slave = mpitask, slavearg = args, nslaves = count, : Internal MPI error!, error stack: MPI_Comm_spawn(cmd="C:/R/R-40~1.2/bin/x64/Rscript.exe", argv=0x00000223DB137530, maxprocs=11, MPI_INFO_NULL, root=0, MPI_COMM_SELF, intercomm=0x00000223DCFCD998, errors=0x00000223DA9FC9E8) failed Internal MPI error! FAILspawn not supported without process manager
 3. Rmpi::mpi.comm.spawn(slave = mpitask, slavearg = args, nslaves = count, intercomm = intercomm)
 2. makeMPIcluster(spec, ...)
 1. makeCluster(nCores)
```

I've tried to install MPICH2 on Windows from [here](http://swash.sourceforge.net/online_doc/swashimp/node9.html), but the final cmd command `mpiexec -validate` always returns `FAIL`.

Could you please elaborate on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `makeCluster(nCores)` is used by more than one package. As such, I use `parallel::makeCluster(nCores)` to solve the issue.